# Save image in Server and link in database PHP Data Objecta PDO OOP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have custom made MVC. I am using PDO. I  want to save image in server and save link to database.

```
public function add(){
    // Sanitize POST
    $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if($post['submit']){
        if($post['title'] == '' || $post['body'] == '' || $post['link'] == ''){
            Messages::setMsg('Please Fill In All Fields', 'error');
            return;
        }

        $images=$_FILES['upic']['name'];
    $tmp_dir=$_FILES['upic']['tmp_name'];
    $imageSize=$_FILES['upic']['size'];

    $upload_dir='uploads/';
    $imgExt=strtolower(pathinfo($images,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $valid_extensions=array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf');
    $picProfile=rand(1000, 1000000).".".$imgExt;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir.$picProfile);

        // Insert into MySQL
        $this->query('INSERT INTO shares (title, body, link, user_id, upic) VALUES(:title, :body, :link, :user_id, :upic)');
        $this->bind(':title', $post['title']);
        $this->bind(':body', $post['body']);
        $this->bind(':link', $post['link']);

        $this->bind(':user_id', 1);
        $this->bind(':upic', $post['upic']);
        $this->execute();
        // Verify
        if($this->lastInsertId()){
            // Redirect
            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL.'shares');
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

With thiscode image is saving in the server but I am getting nothing in database. when I remove image insertion code all the other data stores fine. How Can I upload image in server and save link in database table?

I get the following error

Notice: Undefined index: upic in C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\models\share.php on line 36

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong here. You can try this .

```
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "mypdo";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "123456";

    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);

    $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO shares (title, body, link, user_id, upic) VALUES(:title, :body, :link, :user_id, :upic)");

    $statement->execute(array(
        "title" => $post['title'],
        "body" => $post['body'],
        "link" => $post['link'],
        "user_id" => 1,
        "upic" => $upload_dir.$picProfile,
    ));
```

Comment: The code works with change given below and images are saving with some randim number id in database. Can you tell me how can I show image at website as I am using code given below for retrieving data.

Comment: <div>
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) : ?>
 <a class="btn btn-success btn-share" href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>shares/add">Share Something</a>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php foreach($viewmodel as $item) : ?>
  <div class="well">
   <h3><?php echo $item['title']; ?></h3>
   <small><?php echo $item['create_date']; ?></small>
   <hr />
   <p><?php echo $item['body']; ?></p>
   <br />
   <img src="<?php $item['$tmp_dir, $upload_dir.$picProfile'];?>">
   <br/>

Comment: <a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo $item['link']; ?>" target="_blank">Go To Website</a>
  </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

Comment: Got the solution:<img src="<?php echo $item['upic']; ?>">